# Is there a way to print the source code of Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am an old fashioned programmer and like to print the source code of Google App Scripts. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are not allowed in this site, so I will remove that part of the question.

Comment: Crossposted to [so]. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/36821045/1595451

Answer (score 2):

The Google Apps Script Editor doesn't include print command and doesn't have a command to wrap lines either, so we could say that it's not print friendly.

One solution is to to copy the code and paste it to another app that include better print options. Another alternative is to use a desktop editor. See [External Editor Support for Google Apps Script - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739294/external-editor-support-for-google-apps-script).

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight the script by selecting with your mouse. Then right-click and select print to save to PDF or sent to printer. Haven't found a way to get color output but at least it is possible to save to a PDf or send to a printer.

Comment: Thanks so much.